# Set Variable activity Azure Data Factory v2

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying this new functionality, and when I try to use set variable activity inside foreach loop I cannot select a variable that I declared in a pipeline. 
Also inside IF activity. 
Is it supposed to behave like this? That you cant set variable inside some inner activities, only at the root level of the pipeline?

Comment: Did you see `Variable in Set Variable Does Not Exists` error?

Comment: Yes, when i validate it throws "No Variables Defined in Pipeline", but as I said there is, and if my set variable activity is in the pipeline root i can set it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug, where set variables and append variables activities are not correctly detecting changes when they're nested in another activity. Actively working on a fix for, hopefully will resolve this problem soon :)